Image shape detection, crop and zoom
I am taking thermography pictures in python. I want the camera to detect our square samples, zoom in, and snip the outer edges and apply the temperature gradient. As of now, I have to manually take each pixel, run it through another code in matlab to snip it and get the temperature gradient. An help would be appreciated!
I wonder if image detection could be helpful here.
# Import the necessary Libraries

    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read image from disk.

    img = cv2.imread('Ganesh.jpg')

# Convert BGR image to RGB

    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Apply Canny edge detection

    edges = cv2.Canny(image= image_rgb, threshold1=100, threshold2=700)

# Create subplots

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(7, 4))

# Plot the original image

    axs[0].imshow(image_rgb)
    axs[0].set_title('Original Image')

# Plot the blurred image

    axs[1].imshow(edges)
    axs[1].set_title('Image edges')

# Remove ticks from the subplots

    for ax in axs:
    ax.set_xticks(\[\])
    ax.set_yticks(\[\])

# Display the subplots

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()`

